# utf8 encoding is not working correctly in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am using a magazine name listing program using php. Here I used to manipulate different languages.

I am inserting magazine name into a table. The field name is

```
 tbl_magazine  field type - varchar(32 collation utf8_general_ci
```

when I insert different languages into the table [using google translator]. This correctly inserted into my db [like this viewing in database সঙ্গে পরীক্ষা]. But when I retrieve this using php this record show as `?????` like this.

If anyone know about this, please help me.

Comment: Can you show the code which retrieves it from database, and outputs it? Is your file encoded as utf-8? Also, is your webserver serving utf-8?

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: If you're sure database is dealing right with the text, you need to post the string in codes to examine what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your database connection to UTF8:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8", $conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8", $conn);
```

Also ensure your HTTP responses are interpreted as UTF8:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Who said the OP was using ext/mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  this code at top of your page,

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

For more details, you can refer this tutorial,
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/foreign-languages-using-mysql-and-php.html

Comment: Who said the OP was using ext/mysql?

Answer (score 0):

first your db table must have `utf8_general_ci` collation

and place `mysqli_set_charset ($con, "utf8");` after connection establish...

Comment: Who said the OP was using mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following query before you retrieve data:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

It should help.